# Insert a new line based on the existing table data (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Tags: sql-server, select, join, insert, left-join

Now I have two tables，

`Table A`:

```
  number  date       name
  -------------------------
  a1101   20141209   jim
  a1101   20141210   jim
  a1101   20141211   jim
  a1102   20141209   andy
```

`Table B`:

```
  number  date       
  -------------------
  a1101   20141209   
  a1101   20141210   
  a1101   20141211 
  a1101   20141212
```

Like what you see, when the `number = a1101`, the date `"20141212"` does not exist in `table A`,When this condition is satisfied, I need to insert data into  `table A`：

```
 number  date       name
 a1101   20141212   jim
```

I do not know how to write this sql, look forward to your help.

Add:

When I perform:  `MERGE tableA As Target
USING (Select b.number, b.date, a.name From tableB b Left Join tableA a ON a.number = b.number  )AS Source
ON Source.number  = Target.number  AND

 Source.date = Target.date
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT (number, date, name)
    VALUES (source.number, source.date, source.name);`
Insert the three identical data:

> ```
> a1101   20141212  jim
> a1101   20141212  jim
> a1101   20141212  jim
> ```

Comment: How can I fetch name for a specific number if data not exists in tableA

Answer (score 0):

You can use **INSERT...SELECT** statement.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (number, date, name)
SELECT b.number, b.date, c.name
FROM tableB AS b 
INNER JOIN (SELECT a.number, MAX(a.name) AS name FROM tableA a GROUP BY a.number) AS c ON a.number = c.number 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA AS a ON b.number = a.number AND b.date = a.date 
WHERE a.number IS NULL;
```

Comment: thanks! but "(SELECT a.number, a.name FROM tableA a GROUP BY a.number)"  is error:  a.name is not Aggregate Functions!

Comment: thanks you help! but The name is of type varchar,You can use the max function?And how about the performance of this statement，Because the number of rows in the tens of millions tableA

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL `Merge` like this to do conditional insert,

```
MERGE TableA As Target
USING (Select b.number, b.date, a.name From TableB b Left Join TableA a ON a.number = b.number  )AS Source
ON Source.number  = Target.number  AND       
 Source.date = Target.date
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT (number, date, name)
    VALUES (source.number, source.date, source.name)
```

Comment: thanks，but "ON Source.number  = Target.number  AND ON Source.date = Target.date" is error! Can not have two "on"?

Comment: and I need insert Target.name!When I perform：“... INSERT (number  , date,name )
    VALUES (source.number, source.date,Target.name)” is error:

Comment: Thank you for your patience answer！but Tableb No name in this column

Comment: I found when insert new record , the data does not come from the  table Target, is not it?Line waiting for your reply

Comment: sorry,I did not find this one：(Select b.number, b.date, a.name From TableB b Left Join TableA a ON a.number = b.number  )AS Source。

Comment: This can be run , but it inserts duplicate records

Comment: I need you help,Please hurry right there.Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO #TableA
SELECT DISTINCT a.Number,
       a.[date],
       b.name
FROM   #TableB A
INNER JOIN   #TableA B ON A.NUMBER = B.NUMBER              
WHERE  A.DATE NOT IN (SELECT [date]
                      FROM   #TableA)
```

Comment: Please add some explanations.